# Write a Python code that searches some patterns in a list and returns the matched value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list:

```
items = ['set intf "port1"', 'set action accept', 'set dstaddr "all"']
```

I want the element *'set intf "port1"'* to be returned when it finds *'set intf "port1"'* and *'set action accept'* in the list.

Is there any other way other than the below piece of code that returns the list element when the pattern matches:

```
inner_item = ['set intf "port1"', 'set action accept', 'set dstaddr "all"']
result = [item for item in inner_item if 'set intf "port1"' in item and 'set action accept' in item]
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes, there are arbitrarily many ways to transform this code into equivalent other code. Is there a particular problem with the one you have?

Comment: yes, the above example runs perfectly when I pass only one condition to comprehension

Comment: Do you care if the two are consecutive or only that they both appear in the list?

Comment: So your question is how you can make it work with a second condition? Did you mean to combine the conditions with `or` instead of `and`?

Comment: @JonSG - the sequence of the items in the list could be different. It is also possible that one of them is absent in the list

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I want to make it work with both the conditions and return 'set intf "port1"'

Comment: It looks to me as if you could achieve that by changing `and` to `or`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to change is the second part of the condition. At the moment, you test if both strings are in the current item, but you want to test of the first string is in the items and the second string is in the list:

```py
inner_item = [
    'set intf "port1"',
    'set action accept',
    'set dstaddr "all"'
]

result = [
    item
    for item
    in inner_item
    if 'set intf "port1"' in item and 'set action accept' in inner_item]

print(result)
```

This might be optimized a bit by checking if `'set action accept'` is in the list once, but I'll leave that to you.